# React view is not updating

Tags: reactjs

React view is not updating on calling `setResultArr` inside the `handleClick` method. Wondering what can be the issue.

FYI: I am running bunch of APIs and i want to display the result of those API calls to users as they come.

```
  const [resultArr, setResultArr] = useState<Execution[]>(steps);

  const steps: Execution[] = [
  {
    tag: "Service provider creation",
    function: WebRTCDemoService.createServiceProvider,
    working: false,
  },
  {
    .....
  }
  ]

  const handleClick = async () => {


    for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
      steps[i].working = true;
      setResultArr(steps);

      steps[i].result = await steps[i].function();

      setResultArr(steps);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Flex direction="column">
      <Divider orientation="horizontal" />
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Start</Button>
      <Expander type="multiple">
        {resultArr.map((item, index) => (
          <ExpanderItem
            title={<CustomTitle working={item.working} tag={item.tag} />}
            value={`item-${index}`}
          >
            {JSON.stringify(item?.result)}
          </ExpanderItem>
        ))}
      </Expander>
    </Flex>
  );
```

Comment: Internal modifications to a state atom won't reflect. You'll need to reassign the entire `steps` array.

Comment: @DBS It's a loop with `await`, it's fine.

Comment: @AKX you mean copying to temp array and reassigning it ? I am not getting it ?

Comment: @DBS Yes, it's mutating the state internally (which is the bug), but setting it within an async loop is technically not a problem if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign the entire array to a new object for the change to get picked up, e.g. with a helper like

```
const steps: Execution[] = [
  {
    tag: "Service provider creation",
    function: WebRTCDemoService.createServiceProvider,
  },
  // ...
];

function modifyArrayItem<T extends object>(
  arr: T[],
  index: number,
  changes: Partial<T>,
) {
  const newArr = [...arr]; // Copy the whole array
  newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], ...changes };
  return newArr; // Return the new items
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState(() =>
    steps.map((step) => ({ ...step, working: false, result: null })),
  );

  async function handleStep(i: number) {
    const { function: func } = results[i]; // We will assume the functions don't change
    setResults((results) => modifyArrayItem(results, i, { working: true }));
    const result = await func();
    setResults((results) =>
      modifyArrayItem(results, i, { working: false, result }),
    );
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      await handleStep(i);
    }
  };
  // ...
}
```

Note I'm also using the functional form of `setResultArr` so the changes to `resultArr` meanwhile are picked up.

Comment: this is only showing the last index result. Rest all are empty. Seems like it's overriding the last set value.